# Refresh Session variable after a update in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have code in the global.asax file:

`if (user != null)
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserRole", user.Role.Trim());`

There is a admin function where the role can be changed. The views keep on showing the old session value, ie the value set at the start of the session. How do I refresh the value?

**EDIT**: maybe I should be asking if theres a better way to do it? I use it in the views to show / hide menus and divs.

I have the following code in the _layout.cshtml file:


    `$(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@(Session["UserRole"] == null)' == 'True') {
              //dp some stuff
        }`

For clarity, here is the controller code:

`[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int userid, string firstname, string lastname, string domain, string email, string role, string branch)
        {
            try
            {
                User user = context.Users.Find(userid);
                user.FirstName = firstname;
                user.LastName = lastname;
                user.DomainName = domain;
                user.Email = email;
                user.Role = role;
                user.Branch = branch;
                context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("ManageUsers");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }`

Comment: you are using sane key means ``Session["UserRole"]`` ?

Comment: Yes I am using Session["UserRole"] in the view.

Comment: Where do you update the value? Also, are you sure the views aren't simply being cached?

Comment: I'm updating the value in a controller. The problem is that the value could change between the time the user session starts and now, because the value is updated in the db, but the change isn't pushed back to the Session. Does that make sense?

Comment: @James : i have server side code, in a @ tag so its not being cached.

Answer (score 0):

C# is server side code it is executed at page load so it will have the old value in it you have to get Session value from Server via ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$.ajax({

url: '@Url.Action("GetSession","Home")',
success:function(response)
{

if (response === "") 
{ 
//dp some stuff 

}


}

});

}
```

and in action:

```
public ActionResult GetSession()
{
var SeesionValue = Session["UserRole"] !=null ? Session["UserRole"].ToString() : "";
return Content(SeesionValue );
}
```

Comment: Im not using ajax, also have this value in layout @if(Session["UserRole"] != null){ and it also contains the old value, because the Session["Value"] was set earlier. I added some javascript, maybe after you answered.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am using a global action filter. The filter is registered and then applied to all actions that requires it in the controller.

`public class ShowUserdetailsActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      using (Entities context = new Entities())
     {
       var userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
     var u = context.Users.Where(x => x.DomainName == userName).FirstOrDefault();`

```
    filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("UserRole", user.Role);
 }
```

}